# My Issues (See issue tracking app items, just like My Tasks)

Tags: 2013, my-site, issue-tracking

I really happy with my 'My Tasks' webpart on my mysite. This does exactly what we needed within our company. 
But, next to tasks, we even more work with issues. Is there perhaps a 'My Issues' webpart that we can use just as this 'My Tasks' component? I searched for it, but couldn't find it. Does it exist? Or is there something else that helps me aggregating all issues assigned to me?

Comment: What would be the behavior of an issue?

Comment: I'm talking about items that you add to the "Issue tracking app". I want to aggregate and see all the items that are assigned to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage "My Issues" view of the Issues Tracking App.

1. Edit page where you want to see my issues
2. Add new app part
3. Select the Issues App and set view = "My Issues"
4. Save and close

Comment: That sounds just like what i need. But, i want to put this app on my 'my site' (just as i already have that "My Tasks"), but i don't see how i can make it available for adding to my mysite. I have enabled the "Project Functionality" under Site Features, but that just gives me the option to add a complete issue tracking app to my mysite. That is not what i want, i just want to view the issues that were created on all other sites.

Comment: Ok that will be tricky. What you can do is create a page and place this app (the page should be created on the same site where the app exists). Then edit the my site page and add a Page Viewer webpart. Set the page as the one you created above.

Comment: Okay, so there is no real native element for this, like the "My Tasks" app?

Comment: Not at this point of time.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll play a bit with that workaround you suggested.